# Give an example of b_1,b_2 and b_3 so that no solutions exists

Tags: linear-algebra

Why is this happening? I am not sure what do they mean by why is this happening?

The system is
$x_1+2x_2+3x_3=b_1$
$2x_1+5x_2+3x_3=b_2$
$x_2-3x_3=b_3$

I did Gauss method
$-2p_1+p_2$ to obtain $x_2-3x_3=-2b_1+b_2$ . $p_1+p_3$ to obtain $x_1+3x_2=b_1+b_3$.
$-p_2+p_1$ to obtain $-x_1-3x_2=b_1-b_2$
$p_1+p_3$ to obtain $0=2b_1-b_2+b_3$

I need to give specific values for $b_1$,$b_2$ and $b_3$ that makes the system have no solution.

I will give you 4 examples or cases:
Case 1:
$b_1=-1$
$b_2=0$
$b_3=2$

Case 2:
$b_1=0$
$b_2=2$
$b_3=2$

Case 3:
$b_1=1$
$b_2=2$
$b_3=0$

Case 4:
$b_1=1$
$b_2=0$
$b_3=-2$

The problem is $b_1$,$b_2$ and $b_3$ can be any value and not a specific one. So it has infinitely many solutions instead right?

Comment: If $b_1,b_2,b_3$, doesn't satisfy the condition $b_2 = 2b_1 + b_3$, then the system of equation doens't have a solution.

Comment: Have you considered using matrices for the questions? They are a lot more pleasant to the eye/brain.(imo)

Comment: You can actually use [my answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/610981/what-conditions-must-the-constants-b1-b2-and-b3-satisfy-so-that-the-system-below) to your question and check under what condition the system doesn't have solution by setting one of the determinants not equal to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that
$$2\cdot(x_1 + 2x_2 + 3x_3) + 1\cdot(x_2-3x_3) = 2x_1 + 5x_2 + 3x_3$$
Hence, we have
$$2b_1 +b_3 = b_2 \tag{$\star$}$$
Any choice of $(b_1,b_2,b_3)$ violating $(\star)$ will have no solution.

Comment: what do you mean by star?

Comment: See the star off to the right of the equation?

Comment: I never listed a star. I see a star underneath the arrow toggles but I'm pretty sure that is not what you are asking about because that is suppose to designate a favorite question...Other than that star, I'm don't know of any other star. I thought since b_1, b_2 and b_3 can have any value would make it have infinitely many solutions but apparently this is not the case. how come?

Comment: @user983246 Do you see two ($\star$)'s in my answer? One to the extreme right of $2b_1 + b_3  = b_2$ and other in the last statement.

Comment: Oops...that star was so far away I did not see it until you pointed it out. Awesome heads-up Amzoti and ShikariShambu!